# Cocos2D, UIScrollView and CCMenu

Tags: menu, uiscrollview, cocos2d-iphone, scrollview

I use an UIScrollView to set the position of a CCLayer (when i drag with the finger). It work fine but in this CCLayer i've got a CCMenu with one button CCMenuItemImage.

When i click on this button it's ok. But if i press the button and drag just a little bit the layer, the button stay pressed and become not responsive.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The UIScrollView interferes with the touch events received by CCMenu. It was never designed to share its touches with a UIView.

You have these options:

- find and fix the issue by modifying the CCMenu class
- write your own menu class
- don't use UIScrollView or disable its touch input while the menu is active

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to modify CCMenu and attempt to disable the scroll view's ability to scroll on touch.  Have a look at the UIScrollView properties called `scrollEnabled` and `delayContentTouches`.

By the time the CCMenuItem callback has been called, it might already be too late.